# How to connect Front-end on aws elastic beanstalk to Back-end on aws elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, frontend, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, backend

How to connect Front-end on aws elastic beanstalk to Back-end on aws elastic beanstalk?

I am running both Next.js(React front-end client) on one aws elastic beanstalk instance and Nest.js(Node back-end server) on another aws elastic beanstalk instance.

I also put them on the same security group.

Here comes the problem.

Since they are actually running on ec2 instances, I tried to look up api public IPv4 ip and make client to connect to the api ip listed.
However, it's not working.

How am I able to get Backend api link on elastic beanstalk so that client on elastic beanstalk can communicate with the api?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is your backend publicly available? Does it use public IP or load balancer? Or is it in a private subnets? How do you connect to it?

Comment: Right now I haven't changed any default elastic beanstalk settings

Comment: So you should use EB default url which you are given by your backend EB.